# Android and menus

Tags: android, menuitem

I'm a Java programmer with experience. I started working on a small Android project and i got soooo frustrated by how much Android has complicated programming just to be more flexible.
Exactly, the problem i have is as follows: i have a menu item that i need to use in several menus inside mu app. Is there a way to create a menu item object (possible associate some function to it) and just pass it around so any activity can add it to it's own contex menu?

I have tried this:
Created a "res.menu.mymenu.xml" file that contains a menu item with the same id as menu item from another "res.menu.mymenu2.xml" file. Then i have tried this:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(getMenuToInflate(), menu);
    menu.add(0, R.id.mnhidefrom, 0, ((MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.mnhidefrom)).getTitle());
    HideMenuAction.prepareAndGetHideMeMenuItem(menu, menuInfo); //creating an intent for "hide" menu item that will hold some data needed when user clicks the menu item.
}
```

But no luck... I got "null pointer exception" on "menu.add" line...

Is there a normal, object oriented way, to create a menu item that will know what it should do regardless of anything outside (like,say, menu it belongs to) and just pass it around like any other object and add it to any menu i like (just like i can do with Swing menu and JMenuItems)?

Comment: What does `getMenuToInflate()` return?

Comment: It returns id of context menu that should hold those menu items. ("R.menu.somecontextmenu")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahmad has half the story. This will give you a base of menu options that are always available. The way to add menu options specific to each extending activity is to write a Fragment for it. The fragment will included in the activity layout, but you can make it take up no room or use it for padding. When a Fragment implements onCreateOptionsMenu, the choices it adds are merged with the ones that the Activity created.

Read everything to do with the options menu in this guide for more details:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a normal, object oriented way

Yes there is. It's called inheritance!

Create a base `Activity`in which you inflate the `OptionsMenu` once and extend this `Activity` for all your `Activities`.

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.blabla:
            // do something
            break;
        case R.id.blablab:
            // do something
            break;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Now you can do this:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a BaseActivity as Ahmad described. It works fine.
Now I want to show a special menu item in one specific Activity (which extends the BaseActivity).

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 0:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BlaActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, 0, "Edit");
    item.setIcon(R.drawable.content_edit);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

This works as I expected, but I can't get the new inserted menuitem to get in the first position. 
I need it to be in first position, so it is displayed directly in the ActionBar and the user sees that there is a new option without clicking on the options button.

Edit: I just found the solution myself.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, 0, "Bearbeiten");
    item.setIcon(R.drawable.content_edit);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS); //<-----
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```